# MPI gather doesn't work with customized datatype

Tags: boost, mpi

I tried two ways for the same issue, one works and the other doesn't. The following version works, returning a value of 4.

```
int gather_list()
{
mpi::environment env;
mpi::communicator world;

std::srand(time(0) + world.rank());
int my_number = std::rand();
std::vector<int> tmp_vec;
tmp_vec.push_back(my_number);
tmp_vec.push_back(my_number + 1);

if (world.rank() == 0)
{
    std::vector<int> all_numbers;
    gather(world, &tmp_vec[0], tmp_vec.size(), all_numbers, 0);
    std::cout << all_numbers.size() << std::endl;
} else
{
    gather(world, &tmp_vec[0], tmp_vec.size(), 0);
}

return 0;
}
```

The following version doesn't work, returning a value of 2.

```
class ArchivableVecInt : public std::vector<int>
{
public:
ArchivableVecInt() = default;

explicit ArchivableVecInt(const std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    auto base_ptr = static_cast<std::vector<int> *>(this);
    *base_ptr = vec;
}

template<class Archiver>
void serialize(Archiver &ar, unsigned int)
{
    for (auto i: *this)
    {
        ar & i;
    }
}

protected:

};

int gather_list()
{
mpi::environment env;
mpi::communicator world;

std::srand(time(0) + world.rank());
int my_number = std::rand();
std::vector<int> tmp_vec;
tmp_vec.push_back(my_number);
tmp_vec.push_back(my_number + 1);
ArchivableVecInt my_vec(tmp_vec);
if (world.rank() == 0)
{
    std::vector<ArchivableVecInt> all_numbers;
    gather(world, my_vec, all_numbers, 0);
    for (int proc = 0; proc < world.size(); ++proc)
        std::cout << "Process #" << proc << " thought of "
                  << all_numbers[proc].size() << std::endl;
} else
{
    gather(world, my_vec, 0);
}

return 0;
}
```

I tried 2 processes, while rank 0 returns a value of 2, rank 1 returns zero. Seems the gather(world, my_vec, 0) didn't work, why?

result as below.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does boost MPI do allocation for you? You pass a zero-size vector `allnumbers` as receive buffer to the `gather` call. It looks dangerous to me, but maybe boost does the allocation for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example your receive buffer is a `vector<vector<int>>` meaning that the data is not contiguous. MPI needs contiguous buffers.